# How do I add milliseconds to a DateTime object?

Tags: c#, .net

I can add days:

```
DataTime foo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

How do I add milliseconds?

I don't see a method in the DateTime class to do this.

Comment: There is a [`AddMilliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Thanks to you.

Comment: And thanks for the downvotes. Merry Christmas.

Comment: If you're actually starting with `DateTime.Now` - be careful.  You are assuming that that local time is linear - which it is not in many time zones.  You will find errors if you cross DST transitions or other time zone discontinuities.

Comment: WRT downvoting - Those that choose to do so are justified in this particular case.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question for extensive discussion on this matter.

Comment: To be fair, the three people who cast down votes are the three C# developers in the world who have never overlooked a BCL method. /s

Comment: @DanWilson Just my luck. It's Self-Righteous Day on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an [AddMilliseconds()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var foo = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(100);
```

Or, you can use a `TimeSpan` with [Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var foo = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes there *is* a method [`AddMilliseconds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmilliseconds):

```
DateTime foo = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1234);
```